# How to get the highest values from many columns and show in what rows it happened using pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe from which I want to know the highest value for each column. But I also want to know in what row it happened.
With my code I have to put the name of each column each time. Is there a better way to get all highest values from all columns?

```
    df2.loc[df2['ALL'].idxmax()]
```

THE DATAFRAME

[image]

WHAT I GET WITH MY CODE

[image]

WHAT I WANT

[image]

THE DATAFRAME

Comment: Can you include code and dataframes as text, not pictures?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can stack your frame and then sort the values from largest to smallest and then take the first occurrence of your column names.

First I will create some fake data

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10,5), columns=list('abcde'),
                 index=list('nopqrstuvw'))
df.columns.name = 'level_0'
df.index.name = 'level_1'
```

Output

```
level_0         a         b         c         d         e
level_1                                                  
n        0.417317  0.821350  0.443729  0.167315  0.281859
o        0.166944  0.223317  0.418765  0.226544  0.508055
p        0.881260  0.789210  0.289563  0.369656  0.610923
q        0.893197  0.494227  0.677377  0.065087  0.228854
r        0.394382  0.573298  0.875070  0.505148  0.334238
s        0.046179  0.039642  0.930811  0.326114  0.880804
t        0.143488  0.561449  0.832186  0.486752  0.323215
u        0.891823  0.616401  0.247078  0.497050  0.995108
v        0.888553  0.386260  0.816100  0.874761  0.769073
w        0.557239  0.601758  0.932839  0.274614  0.854063
```

Now stack, sort and drop all but the first column occurrence

```
df.stack()\
  .sort_values(ascending=False)\
  .reset_index()\
  .drop_duplicates('level_0')\
  .sort_values('level_0')[['level_0', 0, 'level_1']]

   level_0         0 level_1
3        a  0.893197       q
12       b  0.821350       n
1        c  0.932839       w
9        d  0.874761       v
0        e  0.995108       u
```